# Dynamic Multidimensional Object in Javascript like PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

In `PHP` we can easily do this

```
<?php

$arr['layer1']['layer2'] = "value"; // works fine in PHP
```

Returns :

```
 Array(
  [layer1] => Array(
    [layer2] => "value"
  )
)
```

This code will work fine, because **Variable decliaration in `php` is not requred**
But in Javascript variable decliaration is a must. 
So, this don't work in `Javascript`

```
var obj['layer1']['layer2'] = "value"; // doesn't work on JS

// sorry I can't use the code below
var obj = {};
obj['layer1'] = {};
obj['layer1']['layer2'] = "value";

// I can't use this also
var obj = {
  "layer1" : {
     "layer2" : "value"
  }
};
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'layer2' of undefined

I can't use this code because I need to create an object **Dynamically**. And there is no fixed key even fixed layer in it. So, **I need something that will exactly work as a PHP**

Comment: Javascript don't have associative arrays like PHP. You have to create objects and iterate through them. To iterate through the object you can use either Object.keys or for-in loop

Comment: Can you give an example of how you get the dataset that needs to be in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to override the `obj` variable ? then you can use following.

```js
var object = {
      layer1: {
            layer2: 'value2'
      }
};

object = {
      ...object, ...{
            layer3: {
                  layer4: 'value4'
            }
      }
}

console.log(object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Idea. But not the proper answer that I wanted. But i am taking your idea, It may help in some case.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Define the outer object, where the value of one of its values is another object, and so fourth:

```js
var obj = {
  layer1: {
    layer2: 'value'
  }
};

console.log(obj.layer1.layer2);
```

Comment: Works fine for me, what problems are you encountering with it?

Comment: I already said that, I have to make it dynamically. I dont know how many layers are there and what gonna be the layer name.. It will be set as a condition.

Comment: You can use recursive function where you can decide the depth level based on typeof the next value.

Comment: @RinkeshGolala yes.. Thats might be a way. Thanks for better idea.